# nested rails resource collection getting 404 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.  I'm using Rails 3.2.12.  The following routes work in development mode when posting an array of values to /admin/sections/3/banner_entities/reorder but in production mode i keep getting a 404 (I doesn't work regardless of the :section_id)

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :sections, :only => [:index, :show] do
        resources :banner_entities do
            collection do
                post :reorder
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The controller lives in

```
/admin/banner_entities_controller.rb
```

Also rake routes gives me:

```
reorder_admin_section_banner_entities POST   /admin/sections/:section_id/banner_entities/reorder(.:format)               admin/banner_entities#reorder
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're making a post request in production? Could you show the relevant log entries?

Comment: So it looks like i missed something small, looked at the log and it turns out my cache sweeper was looking for a non-existing route.  Working now, thanks for putting me on the right track.